# How do I convert a numpy array divided into 6 sections lists, each containing 6 more lists with RGBA values into an accurate 6 by 6 pixel image?

Tags: python, numpy

I've tried everything, tkinter, turtle, PIL, matplotlib.
I want to convert this:

```
[[[255   0   0 255] (contains RGBA values)
  [255   0   0 255]
  [255   0   0 255]
  [255 127  39 255]
  [255 127  39 255]
  [255 127  39 255]]

 [[255   0   0 255]
  [255   0   0 255]
  [255   0   0 255]
  [255 127  39 255]
  [255 127  39 255]
  [255 127  39 255]]

 [[255   0   0 255]
  [255   0   0 255]
  [255   0   0 255]
  [255 127  39 255]
  [255 127  39 255]
  [255 127  39 255]]

 [[ 34 177  76 255]
  [ 34 177  76 255]
  [ 34 177  76 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]]

 [[ 34 177  76 255]
  [ 34 177  76 255]
  [ 34 177  76 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]]

 [[ 34 177  76 255]
  [ 34 177  76 255]
  [ 34 177  76 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]
  [  0 162 232 255]]]
```

code I have tried:

```
plt.axis('off')
plt.imshow(outputPixels, aspect = 'auto')
plt.show()

Image.fromarray(outputPixels, mode='RGB')

(I would show you Tkinter, but I deleted it)
(Just think a for loop adding and gridding a canvas the size of a pixel)
into a 6 by 6 image.
```

At first, I used PIL imsave, but that was inaccurate.
Then matplotlib, but I couldn't change the size.
I even used tkinter canvases (each canvas represents a pixel), but everything was black.

[MatPlotLib Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2bIc.png)

[PIL inacurrate image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uGU4.png)

Comment: Can you include some of the code you've tried?

Comment: That looks like a (6,6,4) shaped array.  With `matplotlib`, `plt.imshow(arr)` should work, displaying a 6x6 pixel image.  What was wrong with `PIL`?  (I made a test array with `np.zeros((6,6,4),int)` and filled in various combinations of values.  The print layout is like yours.

Comment: Henry Woody I added the code

Comment: hpaulj
The PIL image did not represent the RGBA values

Answer (score 0):

your array shape is good you just need to use pyplot.imshow method which take array of shape (n,m,4) and plot the image

following code is working

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


arr = [[[255,   0,   0, 255,], 
  [255,   0,   0, 255,],
  [255,   0,   0, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],],

 [[255,   0,   0, 255,],
  [255,   0,   0, 255,],
  [255,   0,   0, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],],

 [[255,   0,   0, 255,],
  [255,   0,   0, 255,],
  [255,   0,   0, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],
  [255, 127,  39, 255,],],

 [[ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],],

 [[ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],],

[[ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [ 34, 177,  76, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],
  [  0, 162, 232, 255,],]]


plt.imshow(arr)
```

the image you are getting is 6X6 but your image has same color first 3 pixels so you see it divided in 4 sections. you can verify it by plotting only part of the image

```py
plt.imshow(arr[:3])

plt.imshow(arr[-3:])
```

Comment: these lines ```plt.imshow(arr[:3])

plt.imshow(arr[-3:])``` show 1st half and second half of the image, you can see there each half has 3 sections

Comment: Yes I know that, but I want my image to be 6 by 6 PIXELS not sections